# Magento - Display inventory available qty on category page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, magento-enterprise, inventory

How can I can I display the available inventory level on the category page? 
I have the code below in the category screenshot below, however the inventory displays 0 in the default.phtml file.

```
<?php echo 'Qty: '.$_product->getStockItem()->getQty() ?>
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
echo $stock->getQty();
```

Comment: Thank you @Akhilesh How can I insert the round variable to round the number. Currently it is showing for example 12.00.

Comment: use <?php echo round($stock->getQty()); ?>

Comment: Thank you@Akhilesh. That worked. This is the code   '<?php echo $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct ($_product); echo round($stock->getQty()); ?> '

Comment: Thank you @Akihilesh, I did mark the question as answered. Please mark my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the following to output inventory count.

```
    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product_id);
    echo round($stock->getQty());
```